# Trying to consume a C# web service in VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I have a web service that was written by another developer here.

The Service itself was written in C#.  There are two places in which I am calling it.  In my windows VB.NET application, it works great - I can add the reference to the web service and invoke an instance of the class.

However, when I try to do the exact same thing in an ASPX.VB code behind page I find that even though intellisense recognizes the class and the methods, when I try to create an object as a new instance of that class, tells me it is not defined.

For our purposes here I will call the service instance myWebSvc
At the top of this service, the public class is named "Service1"

I have added the web reference to the web site, and I get to the point where I try to set it up as such:

```
Dim objSvc as myWebSvc.Service1 = New myWebSvc.Service1
```

This causes me to get the following compliation error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'myWebSvc.Service1' is not defined.

I've found some hints that perhaps I need to make a proxy service to call it but I can't seem to get that to function either.  The reference is located in App_WebReferences/myWebSvc/ and has a .discomap file as well as a .disco and .wsdl files nested under that.

Comment: Is this a web site, or a web application project?

Comment: It's an intranet web site page - mixed the web site has both asp classic & asp.net pages.

Comment: It is important to specify that you're  using a web site. Most developers are not using them (for good reason), and they behave differently in many ways. Among other things, your service reference is probably being interpreted at run-time, whereas with a web application, it would have been compiled when the solution was compiled.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I would make this a web application if I could, but too much of it is still in asp classic at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy class most likely isn't named `myWebSvc.Service1`. Look at the generated code (I guess it's Reference.vb in your myWebSvc directory) and remember what name you typed in when you generated it, and you'll discover you need something like:

```
myWebSvcReference1.Service1Client
```

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I was finally able to find the program that generates the proxy class for you.  Then I added the VB file under app_code and viola.  it worked!